# missing initSID.ora

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I learning to use Oracle database, and I just installed Oracle Database 12c Release 2 on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I login as **sysdba** with this following command:

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

So far all thing working and I got this message:

```
Connected to an idle instance.
```

Now, I want to start my server with this following command:

```
SQL> STARTUP
```

But, the thing that make me confuse are I got this error message:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'
```

I checking it out on that directory, and the **initSID.ora** was missing.

So, where I can find the missing file..?, how to fix it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out this by creating a database following this [tutorial](https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/how-to-use-the-database-configuration-assistant-dbca-to-create-databases-in-oracle-12c/).

Answer (score 3):

That file is created by [DBCA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/creating-and-configuring-an-oracle-database.html#GUID-99A93810-62B1-4707-9995-89B3D0B5FB56), but no necessarily, typically you will have an SPFILE.

If you want to create a database manually, then you need to create this file manually: [Create the Initialization Parameter File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/creating-and-configuring-an-oracle-database.html#GUID-62BADEF5-9C27-4C11-B143-2BCB9E5C3ABF).

In a clustered environment that file is typically created by Grid Infrastructure and it has a single line that is a reference to the SPFILE.

Some advice in case you want to avoid wasting a lot of your time:

Forget Ubuntu. For Oracle, it is not a supported distribution, you will encounter and have to solve problems that noone else cares about because they simply do not exist in a supported environment. Just install VirtualBox, and do everything inside an Oracle Linux virtual machine.

If you want some nice and simple tutorials, do not just follow any random blog post.

https://oracle-base.com/ is a nice starting place for beginners.

For example:

[VirtualBox : Creating a New Virtual Machine (VM)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/vm/virtualbox-creating-a-new-vm)

[Oracle Linux 7 (OL7) Installation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/oracle-linux-7-installation)

[Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2) Installation On Oracle Linux 6 (OL6) and 7 (OL7)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-and-7)

Comment: Thanks for your advice Man, I appreciate it :)